# MSBuild ReadLinesFromFile all text on one line

Tags: deployment, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

When I do a ReadLinesFromFile on a file in MSBUILD and go to output that file again, I get all the text on one line. All the Carriage returns and LineFeeds are stripped out.

```
<Project DefaultTargets = "Deploy"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
<Import  Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

<ItemGroup>
    <MyTextFile Include="$(ReleaseNotesDir)$(NewBuildNumber).txt"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="ReadReleaseNotes">
    <ReadLinesFromFile
        File="@(MyTextFile)" >
        <Output
            TaskParameter="Lines"
            ItemName="ReleaseNoteItems"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
</Target>

<Target Name="MailUsers" DependsOnTargets="ReadReleaseNotes" >
    <Mail SmtpServer="$(MailServer)"
        To="$(MyEMail)"
        From="$(MyEMail)"
        Subject="Test Mail Task"
        Body="@(ReleaseNoteItems)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Deploy">
    <CallTarget Targets="MailUsers" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

I get the text from the file which normally looks like this

> ```
> - New Deployment Tool for BLAH
>
> - Random other stuff()""
> ```

Coming out like this

> ```
> - New Deployment Tool for BLAH;- Random other stuff()""
> ```

I know that the code for ReadLinesFromFile will pull the data in one line at a time and strip out the carriage returns.

Is there a way to put them back in?
So my e-mail looks all nicely formatted?

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem here is you are using the `ReadLinesFromFile` task in a manner it wasn't intended.

> **ReadLinesFromFile Task**
>   Reads a list of *items* from a text file.

So it's not just reading all the text from a file, it's reading individual items from a file and returning an item group of ITaskItems.  Whenever you output a list of items using the `@()` syntax you will get a separated list, the default of which is a semicolon.  This example illustrates this behavior:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

    <ItemGroup>
        <Color Include="Red" />
        <Color Include="Blue" />
        <Color Include="Green" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="ItemGroup Color: @(Color)" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

And the output looks like this:

```
  ItemGroup Color: Red;Blue;Green
```

So while the best solution to your problem is to write an MSBuild task that reads a file into a *property* as a string an not a list of items, that's really not what you asked for.  You asked if there was a *way* to put them back, and there is using [MSBuild Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx).

Transforms are used to create one list from another and also have the ability to transform using a custom separator.  So the answer is to transform your list read in using `ReadItemsFromFile` into another list with newlines.  Here is an example that does just that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

    <ItemGroup>
        <File Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(File)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
        </ReadLinesFromFile>

        <Message Text="FileContents: @(FileContents)" />
        <Message Text="FileContents Transformed: @(FileContents->'%(Identity)', '%0a%0d')" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Test.text looks like:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

And the output looks like this:

```
[C:\temp]:: msbuild test.proj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.21022.8
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.1433]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/8/2008 8:16:59 AM.
Project "C:\temp\test.proj" on node 0 (default targets).
  FileContents: Red;Green;Blue
  FileContents Transformed: Red
Green
Blue
Done Building Project "C:\temp\test.proj" (default targets).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.03
```

What's going on here is two things.

```
@(FileContents->'%(Identity)', '%0a%0d')
```

- We are transforming the list from one type to another using the same values (`Identity`) but a custom separator `'%0a%0d'`
- We are using [MSBuild Escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186.aspx) to escape the line feed (`%0a`) and carriage return (`%0d`)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thank dude!!

I knew I could do it writing a custom task, but I would rather not have a bunch of Custom tasks about the place if I can do it with the syntax at hand.

Thanks again!! :-)

Answer (score 43):

If you are using MSBuild 4.0, you can do the following instead, to get the contents of a file:

```
$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($FilePath))
```

Comment: that's the working link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild-property-functions/

Answer (score 5):

Instead of @(FileContents->'%(Identity)', '%0a%0d') I believe you can do @(FileContents, '%0a%0d')

Answer (score 3):

You can use WriteLinesToFile combined with

```
$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(SourceFilePath))):

< WriteLinesToFile File="$(DestinationFilePath)"  Lines="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(SourceFilePath)))"
                      Overwrite="true" 
                      />
```

This will copy your file exactly at it is.