# How concatenate files in MSBuild and preserve tabs and spaces

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to concatenate a few files during my build but the way I tried strips out the tabs and spaces leaving the output unformatted.

```
<CreateItem Include="Scripts\ApplicationModule.d.ts; Scripts\AccountModule.d.ts; Scripts\FeedModule.d.ts;">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ApplicationDefinitionFiles" />
</CreateItem>

<ReadLinesFromFile File="%(ApplicationDefinitionFiles.FullPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="ApplicationDefinitionLines" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>

<WriteLinesToFile File="Scripts\ApplicationDefinition.d.ts" Lines="@(ApplicationDefinitionLines)" Overwrite="true" />
```

What's the way to preserve formatting?

Comment: This question may help/explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272518/msbuild-readlinesfromfile-all-text-on-one-line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what I ended up with when faced with the same problem:

```
<Target Name="ConcatenateScripts">
  <!-- List all the files you want to concatenate. -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ConcatFiles Include="
        Scripts\ApplicationModule.d.ts; 
        Scripts\AccountModule.d.ts;
        Scripts\FeedModule.d.ts;"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Read the contents of the files (preserving tabs/spaces). -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <FileContents Include="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(ConcatFiles.Identity)))"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Write the result to a single file. -->
  <WriteLinesToFile File="Scripts\ApplicationDefinition.d.ts" Lines="@(FileContents)" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>

<!-- Concatenate scripts on AfterBuild. -->
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <CallTarget Targets="ConcatenateScripts"/>
</Target>
```

This is a modified version of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475046.aspx) but using `$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(...)` instead of the `ReadLinesFromFile` task, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9335100/121146).

Comment: VS2013 Premium V12.0..31101.00 Update 4.
When file has heading tabs or spaces, the concatenated result doesn't. All lines start from the left edge with text. I'm using other elements than <ConcatFiles> or <FileContents>, but isn't important. BTW, if I set build output to "Diagnostics" VS prints that ReadLinesFromFile is invoked within the target.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I'm on 2015 update 2.  The only hard part was finding this post! :)

Comment: THANK YOU!  PS  If you want to put some "white space" between the concatenated files, you can just tack in some extra stuff.  Example:  <FileContents Include="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(InFiles.Identity)))%0a%0a%0aWHITESPACE%0a%0a%0a"/>       where %0a is a carriage return.